# Clicking on the column sort changes the color of the column row which we click - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, grails

[image: Table]

Clicking on the column sort changes the color of the column or highlight the column row (based on onclick event of the user)

I have a table with tablesorter , it sorts the columns asc and desc.(code below). 
Each column - if I click - it will sort.. 
For eg.. If I click on Study ID, it sorts the rows.. and I want the color to be changed when the sorting happens so that I will know based on which column I sort.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Study ID</th>
        <th>Study Title & Description</th>
        <th>Route</th>
        <th>Indication1</th>
        <th>Therapeutic Area</th>
        <th>Molecule</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

I tried this script to sort - highlight the column row which we sort :

http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/ - Not working out.

I am using this in grails 2.1.1 javascript

I tried this :

```
<script>
$( "#th1" ).click(function() {
    alert("dsdsf");
    $("th").css({"font-color": "yellow", "font-size": "20%"});
});
</script>
<thead>

    <tr>
        <th id="th1">Study ID</th>
        <th>Study Title & Description</th>
        <th>Route</th>
        <th>Indication1</th>
        <th>Therapeutic Area</th>
        <th>Molecule</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: Could you provide the JavaScript you have used/a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please

Answer (score 1):

Just grab the td's and process as shown here,[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fxwu1wko/5/)

```
$("td").click(function () {
    var columnNo = $(this).index();
    $(this).closest("table")
        .find("tr td:nth-child(" + (columnNo + 1) + ")")
        .css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Comment: I dont want to change the background color - I want to change the color of the column which we click to sort

Comment: I tried this : <script>
$( "#th1" ).click(function() {
 alert("dsdsf");
 $("th").css({"font-color": "yellow", "font-size": "20%"});
});
</script>
<thead>
   
 <tr>
  <th id="th1">Study ID</th>
  <th>Study Title & Description</th>
  <th>Route</th>
  <th>Indication1</th>
  <th>Therapeutic Area</th>
  <th>Molecule</th>
 </tr>
</thead>

Answer (score 0):

Here is pure CSS solution, you just need to add `sorted` class to your column.

https://jsfiddle.net/s6b3kms1/

It's based on [this](https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/).